# How to update a constraint in cplex using Python

Tags: python, optimization, cplex

I am using CPLEX to solve a transshipment problem. First, I use add_constraints function to add three sets of constraints for the standard transshipment problem as follows:
[image]

Now since there is a link from one supply node to one demand node, I need to modify two constraint. Any one know how to fulfill this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code image has to be replaced with text code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Making optimization simple with python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) see [get and set coef](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoogetandsetcoef.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
ctKids=mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve(log_output=False,)


for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)


for v in ctKids.iter_variables():
   print(v," --> ",ctKids.lhs.get_coef(v))

#And now let us allow 5 more kids per bus
print("And now let us allow 5 more kids per bus")

for v in ctKids.iter_variables():  
   ctKids.lhs.add_term(v,5)


for v in ctKids.iter_variables():
   print(v," --> ",ctKids.lhs[v])

mdl.solve(log_output=False,)


for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Comment: Thanks. After reading this example and some try-and-error, I was able to figure it out. I answer it beneath in case other people have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign names to those constraints as

```
    supply=opt_md.add_constraints(((sum(x[i,j] for j \

        in range(n))<=s[i]) for i in range(m)),\

        names='supply')

    demand=opt_md.add_constraints(((sum(y[j,k] for j \

        in range(n))==d[k]) for k in range(p)), \

        names='demand')

    transship=opt_md.add_constraints(((sum(x[i,j] for i \

        in range(m))==(sum(y[j,k] for k \

        in range(p)))) for j in range(n)), \

        names="transship")
```

Suppose that node 2 is a supply node and node 8 is a demand node. Suppose that we add a direct link from 2 to 8 with variable shipping cost of 4. First, add a decision variable
x_2_8=opt_md.continuous_var(name='x_2_8',lb=0)

We then need to update two constraints (one for supply node 2 and the other for demand node 8):

```
supply[1].lhs=supply[1].lhs+x_2_8

demand[3].lhs=demand[3].lhs+x_2_8
```

A new term 4*x_2_8 should be added to the objective function.